# Error trying to debug winforms application in visual studio 2008

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-2008

I have a solution working at VS 2008. It contains lots of projects. I installed VS 2010 and it converted all projects to work in .NET Framework 4. After I've found that there is no profit to use VS 2010, I decided to move back to 2008. After that debugging is totally broken. 
When I select project and select "Debug -> Start New Instance" It says me:

***Error while trying to run project: Unable to start debugging.
The remote computer does not have a CLR version which is compatible with the remote debugging components. To install a compatible CLR version, see instructions in the 'Remote Component Setup' page on Visual Studio CD.***

I tried to remove both VSs and install 2008, removed .NET Frameworks and installed 3.5.
I don't understand why it wants remote debugger while I'm trying just to run winforms application on local machine. The same happens for Console applications.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: try change target from anycpu to x86

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. ((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your issue with Visual Studio or with the 4.0 Framework?

If it is with just the framework. I would change your projects Target Framework back to your former framework and continue to use VS2010.

[image]

If it is with VS2010, I would do the same thing as above before trying to run it in VS2008 again. You will probably have to edit the project files to the proper VS Version.

See this [`CodeProject Article`](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/80953/Converting-VS2010-Solution-to-VS2008) for an example what needs to be done.

or better yet if  you have source control just restore your Solution from there.

Comment: That seems to be a working solution, but I decided to work on VS 2010. Thanks for your detailed response.